# PHP installation failed?

Tags: php, windows, installation

I recently download PHP from [here](http://windows.php.net/) to install on Windows. I extracted all the contents of the file into a file called php located in C:\php. I added the path to the environment variables. I tried to run php -v on the command prompt but I get nothing, not even an error message. Am I missing something? Something wrong with the installation?

Comment: Did you restart your computer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for PHP to be properly installed, I needed to have the Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2012 installed. I did not have it installed but after all said and done I tried verifying if PHP is installed and it was.

Comment: The VC requirement for current versions of PHP are as follows:
PHP 5.6 -- VC11 (aka 2012)
PHP 5.5 -- VC11 (aka 2012)
PHP 5.4 -- VC9 (aka 2008)

Answer (score 0):

Php is server side script that parses php code and return html output for your browser.

Get a web server and enable php. Try running php code on web server. point your browser to the location.

There are many free web servers available.